# LINQ count issue on an observable collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have an observable collection and I'm trying to count the number of objects where "IsActive" = true.  This looks like it should work, but I get an error saying "Count can't be used as a method".  Anyone know how to do this?

```
int count = createAndDisplayViewModel.AvailableMonitorsForAddOC.Count(p => p.IsActive);
```

Comment: Have you added `using System.Linq;` in the top of the file?

Comment: Son of a gun.  That's it.  sheesh a little intellisense help would have been nice.  ;-)  Thank you!!!

Comment: May we have an [MCVE]? Or every information you can give: What is the type of AvailableMonitorsForAddOC ? Is Count in the list of Itelisense suggestion? Could it be a Typo? Is Linq included? What is the target framwork ?

Comment: This can be solve by your fellow [light bulb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-light-bulb-suggestions?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `using System.Linq` in the top of the file.

The misleading error message ("Count can't be used as a method") is given because the collection has a `Count` property, and it does not know about the extension method.